# bayesian prior on the range parameter (spatial statistics)

Tags: range, spatial, bayesian

I am working with a bayesian hierachical model for precipitation, and I need to specify priors for the parameters describing spatial dependence; sill and range. My question is, the priors become different when using different units on the range, f.eks. meters or km. Am I confused? Should the units represent the type of coordinate system used (in this case UTM)? I appreciate any input.

Comment: I would say that units doesn't matter. There are just numbers in WinBUGS, no units. It's up to you how you interpret the numbers.

Comment: Ok. But if we for instance need a gamma prior for the range, the expected value (mean) is equal to the shape parameter (a) times the scale parameter (b) of the gamma distribution (mean=a*b). Then the selection of a and b depends on the unit of the mean range...?

Comment: depends on the scale of the numbers, not actually the unit. Try to find as much as uninformative priors possible.